Unity 2D game if/else bug
Basically i'm creating a 2D game and the character have to grab objects, so i did a if/else statement, and the if(grab) condition works, but the else/else if(drop) one don't, I know that i comes from the else if bc if a do if(!isGrabbing) ... and then if(isGrabbing) ... the character grabs the object and immediatly drops it, I tried a switch statement but the bug is the same, and if I do 2 switch statements he grabs and immendiatly drops it too
Here's my code, I hope someone has the solution:
public Transform grabDetect;
    public Transform Holder;
    public float rayDist;
    private bool isGrabbing=false;

 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
 
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        RaycastHit2D grabCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(grabDetect.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale, rayDist);
 
        if(grabCheck.collider != null && grabCheck.collider.tag == "objets")
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
            {
                if(!isGrabbing)
                {
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.parent= Holder;
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.position= Holder.position;
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
                    isGrabbing = true;
                    if(isGrabbing == true)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("isGrabbing");
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = null;
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.position= grabDetect.position;
                    grabCheck.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
                    isGrabbing = false;
                    if(isGrabbing == false)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("isn't grabbing");
                    }               

                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }


I've tried a switch statement, a while loop (that obviously crashed unity), multiple functions for grab and Drop, but the only thing that slightly worked was doing two if statements thaht were activated at the same time, I tried mapping two different keys for grabbing and dropping but it didn't worked as well, I don't think the prolem comes from my code but i don't know 


ok, you do realise that if/else only happens as you press g, 1 frame. thats it?

@BugFinder sure but isn't it supposed to reset for the 2nd frame?

Where is isGrabbing defined? What function is this called from? What function is this code written in? What type of class is it in? Where else is isGrabbing changed? Show more of the workflow, please! Also, use GameObject.CompareTag() instead of == or != with tags.

@TheNomad isGrabbing is defined brefore the Start function, and it's changed nowhere else, the code is written directly in the Update function

"if(grab) condition works, but the else/else if(drop) one don't". What happens exactly? When you say that the false condition doesn't work? That nothing happens, meaning it doesn't drop it? But do you see "isGrabbing" from the Debug.Log() call? What is Holder? The problem with your question is there are variables in use there, but no details. Please post the full script and tell us what each variable does.

@TheNomad i updated my post, you can see all my code, i see the "isGrabbing" from the Debug.Log() but i don't see the "isn't grabbing"

My guess is that after you set grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = null; the new object hierarchy no longer has the "Objets" tag, so any call to CompareTag() would fail (or == as you use but shouldn't). Can you please check that?

@TheNomad So I changed == to CompareTag() and deleted grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = null; but nothing changed, so with some Debug.Log`` statements and the object still has the "objets" tag

This just requires a simple tweak. Just call the parent function from update function. This way as soon as the player hits a key to un-grab the item, you can drop it. I think your code is not working because you have not implemented loop and thus, the code just moves forward without looking if un-grab key has been pressed.

My code is written in the update function, I don't have any other functions beacause I create a new C# file for every functionality of the game, so I don't think that the problem comes from that, except if I didn't understand your answer correctly
